# Jaggery file changes not displaying

Tags: javascript, java, machine-learning, wso2, jaggery-js

I am new to working with .jag files , I supposed to change the interface in web application.just need to add the option in drop down list.

Is that changing .jag file is enough?

I need to add following code (new option in drop down) under select code.

How can I change the interface when working with .jag file?

Correct me If I am wrong.

```
<optgroup label="Time Series">
    <option value="TIME_SERIES">TIME SERIES</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is enough. AFAIK Jaggery pre compile .jag files to improve performance since it is [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) based. When the compiler is accessing those .jag files they become "unreacheable" for some time and your modification don't get "deployed".

To know when this is happening I work with .jag files in a workspace folder. When I've done modifying, I make a sync (with rsync in linux) of those files to jaggery deployment folder. When the file in deployment folder is busy, rsync shows me *device or resource busy* and I just wait a few seconds to do rsync again.

Hope it helps.